# c# - EntityCommandExecutionException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating a small news website (for practice) that connects to LocalDB.

I adapted this tutorial to my needs: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

NewsItem class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.WebPages.Html;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace NewsApp.Models
{
    public class NewsItem
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Title is required.")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage="Content is required.")]
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public NewsItem()
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

NewsContext:

```
using NewsApp.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;

namespace NewsApp.DAL
{
    public class NewsContext : DbContext
    {

        public NewsContext() : base("NewsContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<NewsItem> NewsItem { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

In HomeController.cs:

```
private NewsContext db = new NewsContext();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    // This throws EntityCommandExecutionException
    return View(db.NewsItem.OrderByDescending(u => u.ID).Take(10).ToList());
}
```

Finally, Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NewsContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=NewsApp1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="NewsApp.DAL.NewsContext, NewsApp">
        <databaseInitializer type="NewsApp.DAL.NewsInitializer, NewsApp" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Everytime I run it I get EntityCommandExecutionException in Index. When I open Server Explorer in Visual Studio and view the tables under NewsContext, NewsItem is not among them (only _MigrationHistory).

This code was working a few days ago but I manually dropped the table, by using a .sql file with:

```
DROP TABLE NewsItem
```

Since then it hasn't created the table. I tried to troubleshoot the code for a while but then decided to start on a fresh project (thinking it would work) but it still doesn't create the table.

Does Visual Studio save the .sql file somewhere and keep running it?

Can you see any obvious error(s) in my code?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I also have this NewsInitializer.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using NewsApp.Models;

namespace NewsApp.DAL
{
    public class NewsInitializer : System.Data.Entity. DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<NewsContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(NewsContext context)
        {
            var NewsItems = new List<NewsItem>
            {
                new NewsItem{   Title="Some crap test news",
                                Content="Yeah.",
                                Category="News"},
            };

            NewsItems.ForEach(s => context.NewsItem.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in your code there is some part where you create the db? no, so why this app should create a db and a table...

Comment: I also have NewsInitializer that I forgot to put in the post, it's added now. Does that take care of that?

Comment: Do you have migrations enabled? Try to truncate _MigrationHistory. If it does not help try to drop entire database. It should do no harm in your case because the only table you have in your model is gone already but migrations think it is not.